# how to code that you slide your finger on view to get view text one by one?

Tags: android

// A user tries to make meaningfull words by sliding his/her finger on the buttons in the game screen. The buttons are located as a grid, the characters on the buttons are used to make words. I need to know which features (which layout, which view, which listeners, etc..) of android to use, what to use.

User combines adjacent letters without removing finger to make meaningful words. When it comes to last letter, user needs to just remove the finger.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own child of View that has an internal grid of words, draws them to its canvas, and responds to touch events to trace a path across them.  I suggest you study [TileView](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Snake/src/com/example/android/snake/TileView.html); once you understand what it's doing, you'll find that it's actually very easy to write the view you need.